# What should I use, CakePHP 2.x or 3.x, for a similar project?

Tags: cakephp

I have been working on a SaaS Compliance application since October 2014 it is almost done and stable and clients are happy with it. They are using it already and also marketing it. It is built using CakePHP 2.5.5.

Last week the same client came with another similar project. He wanted us to create another Compliance application for another group of clients. Although this is a completely different application, some of the modules, features and plugins could be used from the previous application, since they may be similar in nature and might help to make development faster. Here this what I am confused with. I want to Use CakePHP 3.x for new project but still want to use or migrate 2.x functionality and plugins into it. What is the best way to proceed from here?

Comment: I will suggest to use CakePHP3 because in this way you will find out some thing new and effective regarding CakePHP 3.

Comment: **CakePHP3** +1

Comment: @JacekBBudzynski - Would you also say that it wont be tedious work to convert code written for CakePHP 2.x?

Comment: make sure that if you are going to use Cakephp 3 ... all the plugins you require are compatible with Cakephp 3.x

Answer (score -1):

For the faster development you can use CakePHP 2.x but if you want to use CakePHP 3.x then you have to make few changes according to [3.x Migration Guide](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-x-migration-guide.html).

Comment: I know that?? Anything useful?